# Magento product page image load very slow on chrome browser

Tags: magento2

My store product page images load very slow in chrome browser and it load fast in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You may get a clue by opening the console on Chrome with F12, selecting the network tab and refreshing the page. You will then get the individual element load times and where they are being accessed from (disk cache/memory cache or data read).

Also might be a chrome bug, see here: 
https://www.ghacks.net/2015/03/12/images-slow-down-chrome-to-a-crawl-try-this-fix/